# Is there any python implement of edonkey/emule

Tags: python, p2p

I want deploy a project in google appengine to search edonkey/emule, Is there any python implement of edonkey/emule or ed2k protocol library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon both this question and [y-donkey](http://code.google.com/p/y-donkey/source/browse/#svn/trunk) today. Y-donkey looks like it could fit the bill, though I haven't tested it.

I'm assuming you're looking for client-side code for connecting to a server? If it was client<->client communication you were looking for, I'd have tcp protocol parsing code ready for python (including protocol obfuscation), though it's not available anywhere yet. If you can't get anywhere with y-donkey and think it could help somehow, I could try putting that up somewhere. I'll probably implement client<->server protocol parsing too at some point, but that's still far off, since I don't have that much free time.

If you're going to start writing code from scratch, [hydranode](http://hydranode.com/docs/ed2k/ed2kproto.php) has the clearest documentation on the ed2k protocol that I have seen, though it just documents the bare minimum of packet types and doesn't touch things like protocol obfuscation at all. For protocol obfuscation, [mldonkey](http://mldonkey.sourceforge.net/EDKObfuscation) has the only documentation that is anywhere near understandable. For packet types not covered in the hydranode ed2k protocol documentation, I'm afraid you're just going to have to delve into eMule/aMule/<insert client> source code, and try to get something out of it.

I'd certainly like to hear more about your project and I'm all ears if someone happens to have better references on the ed2k protocol.

Answer (score 1):

After 20 minutes of googling all combinations of python and edonkey/emule/ed2k and visiting all sites of all clients listed under the "eDonkey network" Wikipedia page I can say with near certainty that the answer is "No."